# Able to load the class but Reflection is not showing up the class

Tags: java

I am able to load the class without any problem, but when i am trying to see the loaded classes using Reflections it's not listing up.

I am trying to doing something as follows:

```
//using java assist renaming and saving
    ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
    CtClass cc = pool.getAndRename("com.sample.class1",
    "com.sample.class2");
cc.writeFile("/tmp/class/");

    ClassLoader parentClassLoader = SampleClassLoader.class.getClassLoader();
    SampleClassLoader loader = new SampleClassLoader(parentClassLoader);
    //loading the new class
    Class cls = loader.loadClass("com.sample.class2");


    //use reflection to check out if the class is present
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.sample", new SubTypesScanner(false),loader);

    Set<String> set = reflections.getAllTypes();
    set.forEach(x -> {
        System.out.println(x);
    });
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved by adding the path to reflections object where class files have been saved.
And also we can use existing URLClass loader instead of writing own classloader as follows:

```
public static Set<Class<?>> fetchAnnotatedClasses(final String packageName,
        final Class<? extends Annotation> annotation) {

    final Class[] parameters = new Class[] { URL.class };
    URLClassLoader sysloader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    Class sysclass = URLClassLoader.class;

    try {

        File f = new File("/tmp/class");//can make this configurable
        Method method = sysclass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", parameters);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(sysloader, new Object[] { f.toURL() });
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();


    }

    Field f = null;
    try {
        f = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("classes");
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    f.setAccessible(true);

    ClassLoader clLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    Reflections reflections = null;
    try {
        reflections = new Reflections(packageName, new URL("file:/tmp/class"), clLoader);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Set<Class<?>> clazz = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(annotation);
    return clazz;

}
```